# Clone factory contract variable initialization

Tags: solidity

```
DaoRegistry dao = DaoRegistry(_createClone(identityAddress));
```

_createClone() returns a payable address, but the DaoRegistry constructor is empty. I haven't been able to find an explanation for what is going on here.

Comment: What are `DaoRegistry`, `_createClone` and `identityAddress`? Provide the source code if they are contracts.

Comment: The source is [here](https://github.com/openlawteam/tribute-contracts/tree/master/contracts/core). The same pattern is used [here](https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_createClone` functions deploy an [EIP 1167 - minimal proxy](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167) that target `identityAddress`.

The contract's bytecode is deployed but the contract's storage is not initialized.

The magic is in the `initialize` function called by `createDao`

```
function createDao(string calldata daoName, address creator) external {
    ..
    DaoRegistry dao = DaoRegistry(_createClone(identityAddress));

    ..

    dao.initialize(creator, msg.sender);
    ..
}
```

The `initialize` works here as the "constructor", it is a very common patter used in proxy contracts.

```
function initialize(address creator, address payer) external {
    require(!initialized, "dao already initialized");
    initialized = true;
    ..
}
```

Comment: So the first line
`DaoRegistry dao = DaoRegistry(_createClone(identityAddress));`
says dao is a DaoRegistry at the addreess that _createClone returns. That makes sense. I don't know where that's indicated in the solidity documentation though.

Comment: @Edgeseer Sorry for the late reply. The function `_createClone()` creates a proxy to the contract at identityAddress, it return the proxy address. It has no idea what the target contract do, it just deploys the proxy bytecode and returns. This line `DaoRegistry dao = DaoRegistry(proxyAddress)` is just a casting from `address` to `DaoRegistry`. It doesn't call the constructor.